# Same values does not match in if condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

This is my first attempt in Google Sheets scripting

I try to compare each row of the first column in two sheets.

If any value in sheet 1 is not in sheet 2, I would add it at the end of sheet 2.

This is the code, the compare values never match, I tried ==, ===, with and without toSting(). I never get the flag `found=1`, all values in sheet1 col1 are copied at sheet2 col1.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function Prueba2() {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  sheet.getRange('A1').activate();

  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow, 1);

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var rangeData2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var lastRow2 = rangeData2.getLastRow();
  var searchRange2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1, lastRow2, 1);

  var l1= searchRange.getLastRow();
  var l2= searchRange2.getLastRow();

  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var rangeValues2 = searchRange2.getValues();

  var found=0;
  var arr = [];
  // Loop through array and if condition met
  for ( i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
    found=0;
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 - 1; j++){
      var vi=rangeValues[i];
      var vj=rangeValues2[j];
      if(rangeValues[i].toString() === rangeValues2[j].toString()){
        found=1;     
        break; 
      }; 
    };
    if (found==0){
      Logger.log(rangeValues[i]);
      arr.push(rangeValues[i]); 
    };      
   };
  var toAddArray = [];
  for (k = 0; k < arr.length; ++k){
    toAddArray.push([arr[k]]);
  }

  sheet2.getRange(lastRow2+1, 1, arr.length, 1).setValues(toAddArray);
};
```

**EDIT**

This worked, but I don't know why

```
for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 - 1; j++){
  var vi=rangeValues[i].toString();
  var vj=rangeValues2[j].toString();
  //if(rangeValues[i] === rangeValues2[j]){
  if(vi===vj||vi==""){  
    found=1;     
    break; 
  }; 
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458595/how-to-compare-strings-in-google-apps-script solution by @Harold may give you a way to replace one loop with an indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? The value retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. By considerating this, the script is modified.

### Pattern 1:

If your script is modified, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
for ( i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
  found=0;
  for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 - 1; j++){
    var vi=rangeValues[i];
    var vj=rangeValues2[j];
    if(rangeValues[i].toString() === rangeValues2[j].toString()){
      found=1;
      break; 
    }; 
  };
  if (found==0){
    Logger.log(rangeValues[i]);
    arr.push(rangeValues[i]);
  };      
 };
```

#### To:

```
for ( i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
  found=0;
  for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 - 1; j++){
      // var vi=rangeValues[i]; // This is not used in this script.
      // var vj=rangeValues2[j]; // This is not used in this script.
    if(rangeValues[i][0].toString() === rangeValues2[j][0].toString()){ // Modified
      found=1;
      break; 
    }; 
  };
  if (found==1){ // Modified
    Logger.log(rangeValues[i][0]); // Modified
    arr.push(rangeValues[i][0]); // Modified
  };
 };
```

- In your situation, you might be able to replace `if(rangeValues[i][0].toString() === rangeValues2[j][0].toString()){` to `if(rangeValues[i][0] === rangeValues2[j][0]){`.

### Pattern 2:

As other pattern, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var found=0;
var arr = [];
// Loop through array and if condition met
for ( i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){
  found=0;
  for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 - 1; j++){
    var vi=rangeValues[i];
    var vj=rangeValues2[j];
    if(rangeValues[i].toString() === rangeValues2[j].toString()){
      found=1;     
      break; 
    }; 
  };
  if (found==0){
    Logger.log(rangeValues[i]);
    arr.push(rangeValues[i]); 
  };      
 };
var toAddArray = [];
for (k = 0; k < arr.length; ++k){
  toAddArray.push([arr[k]]);
}

sheet2.getRange(lastRow2+1, 1, arr.length, 1).setValues(toAddArray);
```

#### To:

```
var toAddArray = rangeValues.filter(function(e) {return rangeValues2.some(function(f) {return e[0] && f[0] && e[0] == f[0]})});
sheet2.getRange(lastRow2+1, 1, toAddArray.length, 1).setValues(toAddArray);
```

### Note:

- The reason `vi===vj` of your added script works is as follows.

  - When `rangeValues[i].toString()` and `rangeValues2[j].toString()` are run, 1 dimensional array is converted to a string like `["sample"]` to `"sample"`. By this, `vi===vj` works.

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll study ´function(e)´ looks more elegant and efficient. Is this 100% java?

Comment: @Horaciux Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. This is Javascript. But Google Apps Script is different from the latest Javascript. You can see the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features).